# Are there any references of Muhammad's letter to Khosrow II, outside of Islamic historiography?

Tags: islam, sources, persia, sasanian-empire, muhammad

In Islamic tradition and history [it is said that Muhammad sent a letter to Khosrow II,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khosrow_II#Khosrow_II_in_Islamic_tradition) a Sasanid king who was titled king of the kings, inviting him to Islam.

As history is an interactional phenomenon, thus one way to validate a historical event is to hear it from the other party involved.

In this case, finding a footprint of such a letter in Persian's history would be a historical proof for its existence and essence.

But I can't find one. One reason is that I am not a professional historian. I am only a researcher, mostly doing interdisciplinary research.

Do we have any historical record in Persian's history (not Arabs, not Muslims) to mention this letter and its subject?

Comment: Saeed Neamati  Your question is inaccurate.  Khosrow II was not a king, he had a different rank.  His title was King of Kings of Iran and of non iran.  Furthermore, he was not the last, he has 12 successors listed: .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monarchs_of_Persia#Sasanian_Empire_(224%E2%80%93651)

Comment: @MAGolding, thank you for correcting me. I'll update the question.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_career_of_Muhammad has some links to papers dealing with the claim that Mohammed sent a letter to the Eastern Romsn emperor Heraclius. I think the arguments re. Heraclius would also roughly apply to Khosrow II. AFAIK there is a bit of a lack of primary sources from.the Sasanian empire, so deciding for sure that there was or was not such a letter may be Impossible.

Comment: The wikipedia article says that "Heraclius may never have received it [i.e. the letter from Mohammed]" which I (without having read the sources of the wp article) would interpret as "This letter is not mentioned in contemporary Eastern Riman texts".